# Real life puzzle: Unknown alphabet or shorthand

Tags: cipher, language, real

User [JellicleCat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9055/jelliclecat) posted this on [linguistics stackexhange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/recognize-this-script) a few years ago. None of us were able to come up with a satisfying answer but most seemed to agree that it was an idiosyncratic cipher or shorthand. It means that puzzlers may be better equipped to solve it than linguists.

Anyway, the original question was:

> I've wondered about this script since I saw it years ago. I imagine it's an English cipher. Can anyone tell me?
>
> [image]

He later added in the comments section:

> an intern left it on his notepad on his last day in the office

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This appears to be [Elian Script](https://www.ccelian.com/ElianScriptFull.html). I'm not sure I can read the writer's handwriting entirely (and they seem to have added some nonstandard things like a zigzag for T), but the first few lines read:

> PAR?NRE RENR
>
> ?HE C PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE!
>
> I REALLY WANT MY PEN!

**Edit by OP:** I spend some time to fully decipher it but I think Deusovi deserves the real credit for an answer so I present it as an edit:

> park nre renr
>  the c programming langua#ge!
>  i really want my pen!
>  create a c[=b?]etter interface for reports
>  hey mr flava! flava
>  i reall#y should practice my elian s#cript more
>  the d language is fun to use indeed!
>  i really should practice my elian script
>  mayby # i should  standerdiz ze
>
>  { changed pens }
>
>  testing this pen
>  it writes # mu#a [=much?] faster

Comment: I think it can be assumed that the zigzag with a dot is a T, and therefore the zigzag without the dot would be a K

Comment: Wow! I mean, seriously! I'm gonna have to verify it after working hours but it looks very promising. Thank you!

Comment: @AHKieran Yes, probably! But I was unsure about that first line, so I just left it as-is.

Comment: And again PuzzlingSE (and Deusovi) have thought me something new and lovely. Thanks.

Comment: The zigzag could be 2 letters. AJ

Comment: There's also [this little thing](https://beinecke.library.yale.edu/collections/highlights/voynich-manuscript), maybe you could take a look at it. :)

Comment: @Vilx- [isn't it obvious?](https://xkcd.com/593/) (in case you or someone else hasn't already seen that)